# compare multiple arraylist lengths to find longest one

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, arrays, list

I have 6 array lists and I would like to know which one is the longest without using a bunch of IF STATEMENTS.

"if arraylist.count > anotherlist.count Then...." <- Anyway to do this other than this?

Examples in VB.net or C#.Net (4.0) would be helpfull.

```
arraylist1.count
arraylist2.count
arraylist3.count
arraylist4.count
arraylist5.count
arraylist6.count

DIM longest As integer = .... 'the longest arraylist should be stored in this variable.
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of .NET are you using, and what's the *exact* type? (Sample code would be nice...)

Comment: 4.0. c#.net or vb.net examples are fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is 1 `if` statement acceptable?

```
public ArrayList FindLongest(params ArrayList[] lists)
{
   var longest = lists[0];
   for(var i=1;i<lists.Length;i++)
   {
       if(lists[i].Length > longest.Length)
          longest = lists[i];
   }
   return longest;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Linq:

```
public static ArrayList FindLongest(params ArrayList[] lists)
{
    return lists == null 
        ? null
        : lists.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If you just want the *length* of the longest list, it's even simpler:

```
public static int FindLongestLength(params ArrayList[] lists)
{
    return lists == null 
        ? -1 // here you could also return (int?)null,
             // all you need to do is adjusting the return type
        : lists.Max(x => x.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SortedList sl=new SortedList();
foreach (ArrayList al in YouArrayLists)
{
  int c=al.Count;
  if (!sl.ContainsKey(c)) sl.Add(c,al);
}
ArrayList LongestList=(ArrayList)sl.GetByIndex(sl.Count-1);
```

Comment: Did you mean `foreach`? Also `Count` has to start with a capital `C`.

Answer (score 0):

If you store everything in a List of Lists like for example

```
List<List<int>> f = new List<List<int>>();
```

Then a LINQ like

```
List<int> myLongest = f.OrderBy(x => x.Count).Last();
```

will yield the list with the most number of items. Of course you will have to handle the case when there is tie for the longest list

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the length of the longest ArrayList:

```
public int FindLongest(params ArrayList[] lists)
{
    return lists.Max(item => item.Count);
}
```

Or if you don't want to write a function and just want to in-line the code, then:

```
int longestLength = (new ArrayList[] { arraylist1, arraylist2, arraylist3, 
    arraylist4, arraylist5, arraylist6 }).Max(item => item.Count);
```

Comment: Item doesnt appear in intellisence. Is there a reference i need?

Comment: You will need to add `using System.Linq;`